# I want all visited links to have the same color

Tags: mac, macos

It seems like there should be a simple way for all links that I have clicked on to be highlighted in some way or have a color that stands out. I have not been able to find a universal way to do this on a Macbook Air.

I am currently using Mac OS 10.11.6 El Capitan, and the Safari and Chrome browsers.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

In Safari you can create a custom style sheet and import it in Safari:

E.g. in Terminal enter:

```
echo 'a:visited { color: red !important; }' >> ~/Library/Safari/link.css
```

Then open Safari > Preferences > Advanced > Style Sheet > Other... and choose the links.css.

In older Chrome versions you can modify the file ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/User\ StyleSheets/Custom.css (usually a 0 Bytes file) and add the same line:

```
echo 'a:visited { color: red !important; }' >> ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/User\ StyleSheets/Custom.css
```

---

The support for custom stylesheets has been removed in newer Chrome versions. Here I recommend an extension: [Stylist](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylist/pabfempgigicdjjlccdgnbmeggkbjdhd?hl=en).

Comment: To be safe, use ">>" instead of ">". If the file already exists, the single will erase it and replace it with the new entry whereas the double will append the new entry to the end of a the existing file or create a file if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @Kent Done! Thanx for the hint ;-)